# I have scrapy script, but I can not scrape data, don't knew why

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I run the script, but I got none, but there are data on the url

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class GetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gets'
    start_urls = ['https://www.retailmenot.com/coupons/insurance?u=ZTF65B5PJZEU3JDF326WY2SXOQ']

    def parse(self, response):
        s = Selector(response)
        code = s.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'CopyCode')][1]/text()").get()

        yield {'code':code}
```

I expect 52YR, but i got None

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at the html you are getting as a response?

Comment: No, but now I find the data in the script tag. Thank you

Comment: Good to know. I asked because when using scrapy the page you are scraping might be different from the page you see in your browser, because scrapy don't handle js. I did not look thoroughly the html in my browser here but it seemed like this might be your problem. Since you could find it inside script tags there is nothing to worry then.

Comment: Yes, I find it in script tag, but I don't knew how to extract the data now. Maybe with json ?

Comment: you can try some regex, but I would recommend using scrapy_splash or selenium to handle javascript and take the value from html using XPath

Comment: I used selenium, but I got the data only from one part of the urls, maybe 30%.

Comment: In that code you are not using Selenium. And I would still guess you are not getting your full page with scrapy. If you want success in web scraping you'll have to figure why you are not getting the html you expected to get. Selenium can do the same thing a browser would do, so I would say you could certainly get that data using such a tool. Scrapy splash also works well but It has it's drawbacks

Comment: I have another scipt with selenium, of course. I will try to extract data from script, with regex

Comment: Yeah, I figured. You can try creating a new question addressing why the HTML is not complete using your selenium script, it'll probably be easier for you to get an answer.

Comment: yes, maybe, but now I am trying to get the data from scrapy script tag. Something like this i used in parse, and got string                                                                            data = response.xpath("//div[@id='__next']/following-sibling::script[1]/text()").extract_first()
        s = data[data.rfind("__NEXT_DATA__ = ") + len('__NEXT_DATA__ = {') -1 : ]
        print(s)                                                                                                                 but I don't knew what to do next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this is probably to load the json in the script as a python dictionary and navigate through it to get to the codes.
The below code should get you started:

```
import scrapy
import json
import logging


class GetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gets'
    start_urls = ['https://www.retailmenot.com/coupons/insurance?u=ZTF65B5PJZEU3JDF326WY2SXOQ']
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
    }
    custom_settings = {'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False}

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,
                                 callback=self.parse,
                                 headers=self.headers,
                                 dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        script = response.xpath(
            '//script[contains(text(), "__NEXT_DATA__")]/text()'
        ).extract_first()
        dict_start_index = script.index('{')
        dict_end_index = script.index('};') + 1
        data = json.loads(script[dict_start_index:dict_end_index])
        coupon_data = data['props']['pageProps']['serverState']['apollo']['data']
        for key, value in coupon_data.items():
            try:
                code = value['code']
            except KeyError:
                logging.debug("no code found")
            else:
                yield {'code': code}
```